# Display DocuSign template using template ID?

Tags: docusignapi

I want to open a new page displaying a preview of a DocuSign template depending on the template ID without the need to log into DocuSign, is this possible?

I have not found any guide for doing this in their documents, What they offer though is creating a template inside your app which is not what I want to do since I only want to display a preview of the template for double checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to open a new page displaying a preview of a DocuSign template depending on the template ID without the need to log into DocuSign, is this possible?

Do you mean you want to see the preview of the PDF document(s) in the temolate, complete with the fields (tabs) placed on the page? If so, then unfortunately this can not be done.

If you want to get the documents that the template includes and then display them to your user, you can do that by using the [TemplateDocuments: get](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Templates/TemplateDocuments/get/) method.

You can also retrieve other information about the template and then display it to your user.

Comment: It is the first one and I've confirmed with their support that at the moment is not possible to preview a template from an external source.